# How to compute integral $\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$ without using trigonometric functions and also answer should not contain trigonometric functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am working on definite integrals, and not getting solution for above question, anyone can help me in this?

Comment: Integrate by parts with $u=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Comment: Do you mean without trigonometric functions? You can consider the circle: x^2 + y^2 = 1. What is the integral of y from 0 to 1 mean in terms of area under a curve?

Comment: Yes, use of trigonometric.functions not allowed and answer also free from then

Comment: @maths_freak_007 but you said it is allowed

Comment: I am extremely sorry. I don't want to use any trigonometric functions and answer should be free from them

Comment: There's no getting away from the fact that the answer has a $\pi$ in it, which suggests a close link with trig functions that will make them hard to avoid entirely.  Why are you so desperate to avoid them?

Comment: Yes! Thats where I have stuck

Comment: @maths_freak_007 What definition of pi are you allowed to use?

Comment: You could try using the Maclaurin series for the function and integrating it term by term.

Comment: You could do it in polar coordinates in a way that doesn't (explicitly) use trig functions. Your question is unanswerable since you have said what tools you *can't* use but have said nothing about what tools you *can* use.

Answer (score 3):

The function $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ describes the upper part of the unit circle in the plane centered at $(0,0)$ simply because $x^2 + y^2 = 1 \implies y = \pm \sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Since the integral is the area under the curve, your definite integral is the area of the quarter of the unit circle which is $\pi/4$. See [that](http://tinyurl.com/h9nl9w4).

Comment: I feel obligated to down vote this response because it doesn't actually solve the OP's problem. You've simply asserted the value of the integral instead of computing it.

Comment: I have to admit, I wonder how you would compute this integral without any trigo involved and no "integral intuition" :)

Comment: It all depends on how one defines $\pi$. Without an explicit definition, it's impossible to construct an explicit calculation.